# Meteor FlowRouter getParam error

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, flow-router

I have a route to reset password that setup like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/reset-password/:token',{
    name:'reset-password',
    action(){
        BlazeLayout.render('MainFullLayout',{main:'ResetPassword'});
    }
});
```

So that when I want to access it i can just:

```
var tokenVar = FlowRouter.getParam("token");
```

But when I use it in `Accounts.resetPassword()` :

```
Template.ResetPassword.events({
    'submit #resetpassword-form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var newPasswordVar = event.target.resetNewPassword.value;
        var tokenVar = FlowRouter.getParam("token");
        Accounts.resetPassword({
            token: tokenVar,
            password: newPasswordVar
        });
    }
  });
```

I got an error:

> Uncaught Error: Match error: Expected string, got object

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to [resetPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_resetpassword) should look like this:

```js
Accounts.resetPassword(tokenVar, newPasswordVar);
```

Comment: I get another error using your method: `Unexpected type cast (33:12)`.

Comment: I got it to work. What happen is I took out the `{}` but still use the object way: `Accounts.resetPassword( **token:** tokenVar, **password:** newPasswordVar)`. take that out and everything will be ok.